# Bing Maps v8 AJAX: hiding a layer per javascript

Tags: javascript, visibility, bing-maps, layer

I try to hide a layer of a bing maps ajax control per javascript.
This is what I tried:

```js
    if (map.layers(ii).getVisible()) { map.layers(ii).setVisible(false); }
    else { map.layers(ii).setVisible(true); }
```

Error says "Function expectet". Any ideas?

Comment: `layers[ii]` maybe???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Musa mentioned in his comment, you need to use square brackets to iterate through the layers collection. Using round brackets indicates that you are trying to run a function which the layers collection isn't. Change your code to this:

```
if (map.layers[ii].getVisible()) { map.layers[ii].setVisible(false); }
else { map.layers[ii].setVisible(true); }
```

Comment: Oh, no - what a mistake! Thank you!